# Code::blocks max iterations

Tags: c, codeblocks, montecarlo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Max Array Size in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504807/max-array-size-in-c)

My question is: Does Code::blocks have a max number of iterations for a loop?

I am running a monte carlo and I would like to run a million particles through a for loop. But the max it seems to go without crashing is 110000.

Thanks!

Some more info:

I am using a random number generator seeded by time:

```
    srand(time(NULL));
```

I then want to create a million particles (random)

```
    for(k=0; k<M; k++){
    R[k] = rand()*(1)/(double)RAND_MAX;
    z[k] = -log(1 - R[k])/(1000*U);
```

where M = Num/10 (I want to #define N 1000000)

This is the only thing I can think of that is creating the problem?

Here is an example code that will not work.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){

      srand(time(NULL));

       int j=0;
       int i;
       double A[1000000];

       for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
          A[i] = rand()*(1.0)/(double)RAND_MAX;
           if (A[i] == 1.0){
              printf("Wow!\n");
           }
       }

       return 0;

    }
```

Could this be due to my settings of Code::blocks by any chance?

Comment: There is no max number of iterations. You should give us the error message as well as the relevant code.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not get an error. I just get a popup saying Code::blocks has stopped working.

Comment: Could be a problem with the argument of log being 0.  You should try Valgrind to make absolutely sure.

Comment: 127219 Is the max number I can go prior to crashing.

Comment: Yep, your right about the log. But I still cannot go beyond the 127219...

Comment: Maybe it's just because you have an 8 megabyte array on your stack. Try replacing `double A[1000000];` with `std::vector<double> A;`, and `A[i] = rand...` with `A.push_back(rand...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: this is because the default maximum stack size is 1MB on Windows (but 8MB on Linux).

I don't have a final answer, but I do know:

a) It runs fine from a Linux command-line.

b) Valgrind gives tons of errors of this form:

```
==2465== Invalid write of size 8
==2465==    at 0x804851D: main (test2.c:16)
==2465==  Address 0xbe4480e4 is on thread 1's stack
==2465== 
==2465== Invalid write of size 4
==2465==    at 0x8048521: main (test2.c:16)
==2465==  Address 0xbe4480e0 is on thread 1's stack
==2465== 
==2465== Invalid read of size 4
==2465==    at 0x4081D69: printf (printf.c:35)
==2465==    by 0x8048528: main (test2.c:16)
==2465==  Address 0xbe4480e0 is on thread 1's stack
==2465== 
==2465== Invalid read of size 8
==2465==    at 0x407AC05: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1622)
==2465==    by 0x4081D7F: printf (printf.c:35)
==2465==    by 0x8048528: main (test2.c:16)
==2465==  Address 0xbe4480e4 is on thread 1's stack
```

c) The errors are clearly related to reading and writing from the array.  This simpler version of the program does not cause any Valgrind errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  srand(time(NULL));
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
     if (rand()*(1.0)/(double)RAND_MAX == 1.0){
         printf("Wow!\n");
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your completely correct. I do not know why I am even using an array for the random numbers, so I will scrap the array. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

There's no max number of iterations, but there is a limit on stack size.

When you declare a local variable, the memory is allocated from the stack. The size of `A` is too big to fit in the stack. (e.g. typical stack size on Windows is 1MB, `1000000 * sizeof(double)` is far bigger.)

You can try changing `A` to a global variable or allocate it by `malloc`.